# Massive block on thermally extending spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

Consider a massive block on a spring of some positive thermal expansivity, hanging down from a ceiling (like a pendulum, but it will be only moving vertically). Let us heat up the spring so it expands, lowering the block. The block loses gravitational potential energy, presumably heating up the spring even further. This in turn lowers the block, which again heats the spring, which lowers it even more. Will there be a limit to how low it can hang? In real life - by common sense - this quickly attains some sort of limit, but how does thermodynamics handle this?

As a follow-up to the question, once we cool down the spring, it should contract and lift the block with it - but now, by extracting the heat from the system we increase the gravitational potential energy. If I have a cold reservoir handy, I can do useful work with it. But how do I "pay" for rising the block, if all I did is extract positive thermal work from the system? I guess by having less heat available to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question. There is two mechanisms contributing to temperature increase of the elastic string (let's imagine just a steel string for simplicity, the physics is the same): Heat applied by the experimenter, and potential energy gained by the weight losing height. Let's write this down.

$dT = \frac{1}{C} ( \delta Q + m g dz) $

where $dT$ is an infinitesimal temperature increase, $C$ the heat capacity of the spring/string, $\delta Q$ infinitesimal amount of heat applied by the experimenter, $m$ the mass of the weight, $g$ earth's acceleration, $dz$ infinetesimal lowering. Now let's insert for $dz$ in the linearized regime of thermal expansion $dz = \alpha L dT$, with thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$ ($\approx 10^{-5}/\text{K}$ for steel) and length of the string L:

$dT = \frac{1}{C} ( \delta Q + m g L \alpha \ dT) $

bring the terms with $dT$ together and once again replace by $dz$ differential, then we find:

$dz = \frac{L \alpha}{C - m g L \alpha} \delta Q$

My interpretation of this relation is: As you apply finite amounts of heat externally to the steel string, as long as $C \gg m g L \alpha$ you'll just get some little bit of expansion and the situation will be quite stable (well until the steel get's soft by temperature increase, then you get a runaway effect, but that's a whole new story). But once $m g L \alpha$ is rather close to $C$, the string will lengthen dramatically when heat is applied. But one might be already beyond yield strength of the steel here anyways.

Thinking about it now the analysis is probably insufficient or at least lacking major parts. Like the stress-strain curve of the steel including it's temperature dependence. So it's probably more complex, but maybe this gives you a starting point for further analysis.

Regarding your second point: I think you are spot on. Superficially speaking, the price you pay is in entropy; the warm wire and cold reservoir before having less entropy than the somewhat cooler wire and the somewhat warmer reservoir after. I think it's fair to say that this principle essentially makes everything in our world happen.